# Update Tkinter widget from main thread after worker thread completes

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to update the GUI after a thread completes and call this update_ui function from main thread (like a software interrupt maybe?). How can a worker thread call a function in the main thread?

Sample code:

```
def thread():
    ...some long task
    update_ui() #But call this in main thread somehow

def main():
    start_new_thread(thread)
    ...other functionality

def update_ui():
    Tkinter_widget.update()
```

I tried to use Queue or any flag accessible to both threads but I have to wait/poll continuously to check if the value has been updated and then call the function - this wait makes the UI unresponsive. e.g.

```
flag = True

def thread():
    ...some long task
    flag = False

def main():
    start_new_thread(thread)
    while(flag): sleep(1)
    update_ui()
    ...other functionality
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to be somewhat hypothetical. Here is some that accomplishes that does what you describe. It creates three labels and initializes their text. It then starts three threads. Each thread updates the tkinter variable associated with the label created in the main thread after a period of time. Now if the main thread really needs to do the updating, queuing does work, but the program must be modified to accomplish that.

```
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *
import queue
import sys

def createGUI(master, widget_var):
    for i in range(3):
        Label(master, textvariable=widget_var[i]).grid(row=i, column=0)
        widget_var[i].set("Thread " + str(i) + " started")

def sometask(thread_id, delay, queue):
    print("Delaying", delay)
    time.sleep(delay)
    tdict = {'id': thread_id, 'message': 'success'}
    # You can put simple strings/ints, whatever in the queue instead
    queue.put(tdict)
    return

def updateGUI(master, q, widget_var, td):
    if not q.empty():
        tdict = q.get()
        widget_var[tdict['id']].set("Thread " + str(tdict['id']) + " completed with status: " + tdict['message'])
        td.append(1)
    if len(td) == 3:
        print("All threads completed")
        master.after(1000, timedExit)
    else:
        master.after(100, lambda w=master,que=q,v=widget_var, tcount=td: updateGUI(w,que,v,td))

def timedExit():
    sys.exit()

root = Tk()
message_q = queue.Queue()

widget_var = []
threads_done = []
for i in range(3):
    v = StringVar()
    widget_var.append(v)
    t = threading.Thread(target=sometask, args=(i, 3 + i * 3, message_q))
    t.start()

createGUI(root, widget_var)
updateGUI(root,message_q, widget_var, threads_done)
root.mainloop()
```